# Compro VideoMate TV PVR/FM In Ubuntu 14.04 x64

Tags: 14.04, 64-bit, tv

I have a Compro VideoMate TV PVR/FM In Ubuntu 14.04 x64 and would like to use it with MythTV. This worked OK in 12.04 x64 but not in 14.04 x64 I have checked [this [deleted] question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/470248/problem-with-tv-tuner-compro-and-ubuntu-14-04) but there is no answer on this yet.

Comment: I have got this working with TVTime using the commands...<br>

> sudo modprobe -vr saa7134_dvb

> sudo modprobe -vr saa7134_alsa

sudo modprobe -vr saa7134

sudo modprobe -v saa7134 card=40

I still need it to work with MythTV.

Answer (score 1):

I got this working with MythTV by running commands..

```
sudo modprobe -vr saa7134_dvb
sudo modprobe -vr saa7134_alsa
sudo modprobe -vr saa7134
sudo modprobe -v saa7134 card=40
```

then in **mythtv > capture card setup** I selected **Analog capture card**
 and type Video device: `/dev/video0` and type VBI device: `/dev/vbi0`

then in **Video source setup > Video souce name: RF and Listings grabber: No grabber**

then in **Input connections > [V4L:/dev/vodeo0] (Television)** I set the display name and Video source to RF.

then in channel editor I selected RF and clicked Channel Scan.

It found NO channels but I know that my distribution system is on 65 so I deleted all the channels under RF except 65 by selecting the one I wanted to delete then pressing D.

Once this was done I renamed the channel number to 800 so that it doesn't conflict with the DVB-T and went back in to **Input connections > [V4L:/dev/vodeo0] (Television)** and set the **Starting channel** to **800**.

In the front end I had to type the channel number `800` and press <kbd>enter</kbd> because it doesn't show in the channel list.